# Communicating between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know how to communicate between forms using C#?

In Visual Basic it was easier since each form had it's own instance, with C# it's different.

In the `Program` Class I setup a public and static variable that hold my form:

```
public static FormProcess2 frmProcess2 = null;
```

Then in the `Main` method I create the form and show it up:

```
frmProcess2 = new FormProcess2();
frmProcess2.ShowDialog();
```

Now when that form loads, it load a background process that process XML files.
And the method that process all the files are in another class name `XMLParser`.
So in the `BackgroundWorker` `doWork` I load that method by:

```
XMLParser.Start();
```

Now the question is, how I can modify the `frmProcess2` controls in the `XMLParser` class?
I wanted it to show what's being updated by changing the label text as well as put some nice progress bar there.

But I can't access the `Program.frmProcess2` controls, all I can access is it's defaults only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you can use delegates to communication between windows forms.
Check http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mosessaur/winformsdelegates09042006094826am/winformsdelegates.aspx

For Delegates

***EDIT***

Check
*Delegates (C# Programming Guide)*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx

*Creating Custom Delegates and Events in C#*

http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/02/creating-custom-delegates-and-events-in-c/

*Introduction to Delegates and Events*

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson14.aspx

Comment: I never used delegates before, can I make my own delegate?

Comment: For example, creating one general delegate, in that script I will only update a label and might do some changes on a grid.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create to create my own delegates using the examples you mentioned.

Comment: Now, some problem, I get this Exception whenever I try to update a control:

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblXMLP_File' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Thanks I did that and it's working.
Unofrtunately, the script process a lot, and seems like the control is invoked all the time.
When running in foreground the script proccessed much more faster. Could it be the invoke fault? That it needs to be made again after each step?

Answer (score 2):

To access your UI Controls which are running under UI threads, you need to make delegate function for accessing UI Controls, becoz controls of 1 thread can't be accessed by other threads, in your case your background thread wants to access UI thread controls, this can be done by creating delegate function.

```
    //sample delegate function
    //this function is to request i.e invoke UI thread controls
    private void deleteGridRow()
    {
        if (autoGridView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            autoGridView.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { deleteGridRow(); }));
        }
        else
            autoGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

this function you need to call inside `backgroundworker1_DoWork(){deleteGridRow();}` and you can use this for status :

```
    private void backThread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lableStatus.Text = "your status"
    }
```

[BACKGROUNDWORKER:MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: My problem is that I can't communicated into the already created form, I am taking a look into the delegate form example, seems like that's what I should use.

Comment: Action needs a type, in this case should be what?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class to update the progress.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its intra-form communication that you need. Its background thread to form communication that you need.

In your frmProcess2 subscribe to the BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event. From your doWork method periodically raise that event.

Page 45 of 
Joseph Albahari's [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf) has an excellent  example