# How to let textbox remember its value

Tags: c#, textbox, save

Hi I can't seem to find a solution that works for me. I have two panels: Websiteform and Licenceform.
The user enter his/her credentials in a textbox, their credentials get verified. Now after the credentials have been verified and the user clicks the back button to go from websiteform to licenceform, I need the credentials to still be there when we return to websiteform.

This should only work for the current session as starting a new session will have all controls revert to default values.

Comment: ASP or Winforms?  Think Winforms but you mention Session as well so just making sure.

Comment: I can see where it was unclear. It is a Winforms application. Session was probably not the right the word, I intended it to mean that once you close the application the controls revert to default values.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4438654/449156, it may offer some help.  Other ways are persisting to a db or file of somekind.

Comment: Thanx @BlueChippy! I looked into it and I may have found a solution. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I have used the Application.UserAppDataRegistry.setValue and getValue methods. For my purposes this was sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Many ways to remember the values.but which to use it depends on you.cause you want remain value according the session so .

You can Use Session variable.put the corresponding values like...

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionstringName] = SessionValue;
```

And acess those value..

```
   (TypeCast)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionstringName]
```