# Inheritance with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to use inheritance to pass a string from one form to another using a ref.class. Im looking at it and to be honest I think this should work. But when debugging nothing comes up in my settings textBox...

Here is my reference Class:

```
    class Ref
{

    private String _url;

    public String Sett
    {

        set { _url = value; }
    }
    public String Gett
    {
        get { return _url; }
    }
```

and I am setting it from the main form and getting it from a settings form

Here is my main Form:

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {Ref reff = new Ref();
        this.Text = webBrowser1.Document.Title + " - NHS Cerner Booking Dash";
        textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString();
        reff.Sett = webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString();
```

and finally this is my Settings form

```
    public void load()
    {
        Ref reff = new Ref();
        textBox3.Text = reff.Gett;
    }
```

Im sure this looks a bit complicated. So to clarify I want to take the URL from the main form and set it to my ref.class and then get it from the Ref.class to set it to a textBox in my Settings form. Thank you for looking.

Comment: Why have you got two properties, one with a getter and one with a setter, rather than a single "Value" property with both a getter and a setter? Not that that would fix the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any `Ref` class for this. In your second form create a public property and while creating that form access this property and assign the value of URL.

[Click here to see a post which does similar thing.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d925077a-d013-481b-8ce5-3d1af1cd924e/)

In Form2

```
 public string URL {get; set;}
```

In Form1

```
 Form2 theNewForm = new Form2();
 theNewForm.URL = "your url value";
 theNewForm.Show();
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This solution turned out to be the simplist. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

To start with, this has nothing to do with inheritance.

No, it definitely *shouldn't* work. You're creating two separate instances of `Ref` - so setting the value in one of them won't make it available in the other. You would need to create *one* instance of `Ref` and make *both* forms aware of it - so that they can use it as a shared communication channel.

Personally I don't think that's the best way of communicating between the forms anyway - you should consider using events, for example - but that's why it's not working at the moment.

As noted in a comment, it's very strange to have two separate properties. If I *really* wanted this behaviour, I would have written that class as:

```
public class MutableWrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you create new object when write "new"

```
public void load()
{
    Ref reff = new Ref();
    textBox3.Text = reff.Gett;
}
```

İf you debug you can see reff is empty..

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438654/best-way-to-communicate-between-forms) should help you

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new `Ref` object in each place so the value you set in `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` is on a different object to that retrieved in `load`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a public property in the form that will be opened. This way you can set it just before you open it and use it further on.

Answer (score 1):

Puh, there to start.

At first i suggest you simplyfy your class.

```
public class Ref
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

But this is not the problem.

The Problem is that you have two different instances of your `Ref` class.

So you can do two things.

1. If this is a setting form, you should save the value of `Ref.Url` to Application Settings.
   OR
2. You must pass the instance of Ref to your Settings form.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is ugly, do this instead:

```
class Ref
{

    private String _url;

    public String URL
    {

        set { _url = value; }
        get { return _url; }
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a `Ref` instance inside your `main` class and pass it to your `Settings` class when you create it.  Then you can fill it up inside your `Settings` class like so:

```
myref.URL = "whatevergoeshere";
```

When your `Settings` dialog is finished, you'll be able to look inside your `Ref` object and see what the URL is.

Comment: The annoying thing is I did this was Java in the past and it was really simple at the time. Was clean and now doing it with C# completely forgot everything. Thank you for your help as I will use this as a reference in the future when using a few objects.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you're really not using inheritance... and the issue you're having is the Ref's that you're declaring in two different places are not the same.

```
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ref reff = new Ref();
            //not the same "Ref" as below
        }

        public void load()
        {
            Ref reff = new Ref();
            //not the same "Ref" as above
        }


        //consider using properties instead of members... you get the get/set for free
        public class Ref
        {
            public string URL { get; set; }
            public void Load()
            {
                //do your load set
                this.URL = "What you want";
            }
            //...
        }

        //you can also declare the constructor on the fly if you want.. or call the Load() method
        Ref myRef = new Ref()
        {
            URL = "What you want"
        };
```