# Change property from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, properties

I want to change propetry of several controls from another form.
For example I'm in form2.when I click the button1, I want to change the text of textbox1 in form1 to another text.
How to I can do this.
Thanks.

Comment: webforms or winforms? Asp.net? please show some code and explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communicating between forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373660/communicating-between-forms) and a 100 others.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by binding the first button with jQuery to modify the values of the other form.

example:

```
$("form1 :button").click(function(){ $("form2 #textbox1").val("You clicked button1")};
```

Comment: Assuming the OP is talking about web forms.